# How to determine a winner of a Best of 5 series in excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

### Brief introduction:

I've created an Excel spreadsheet to follow a competitition:

- #### Rules:

  - Team 1 vs. Team 2
  - Team 3 vs. Team 4
  - The winner of the matches is decided by a "best of five".
  - First team to win 3 matches, advancing to the next round.
    (valid results: 3-0; 3-1; 3-2; 0-3;1-3;2-3)
- #### Examples:

  - Team 1 vs Team 2 => Final score 3-0 (Winner Team 1)
  - Team 3 vs Team 4 => Final score 1-3 (Winner Team 4)
  - Next round would be Team 1 vs Team 4

---

### What I want and need help to do it:

When a match ends, I introduce final score in their corresponding cells and automatically should determine a winner based on the final score

(This is the easiest thing if the score of team 1 is greater than score of the Team 2, Team 1 is the winner)

### Some conditions I want to add:

- If both results are equals, it should show a message : "Error, The final score cannot be a tie"
- If both scores are "0", It should show a message like "Not played" (Do not show the previous message related to ties)
- If The final score is 1-0 or 2-0 or 2-1 or 0-1 or 0-2 or 1-2, it should show a message "Error, incomplete result"

---

edit

---

### Example of my spreadsheet

```
     A     B     C      D     E    F     G     H
  |----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
 1|        Round 1
 2|    |-----------|-----|
 3|    |  Team 1   |  3  |
  |    |-----------|-----|
 4|    |  Team 2   |  2  |
 5|    |-----------|-----|          Round 2  
  |                      |    |-------------|----|
 6|                      |    |     Team 1  |    |
 7|                      |----|-------------|----|
 8|                      |    |     Team 4  |    |
 9|        Round 1       |    |-------------|----|
  |    |-----------|-----|
10|    |  Team 3   |  1  |
11|    |-----------|-----|
12|    |  Team 4   |  3  |
13|    |-----------|-----|
  |
  |
```

### What I've done:

- Teams 1,2,3,4 are introduced manually.
- Results of every "best of 5" are introduced manually:

  (cells D2,D4,D10,D12)
- In this example the Teams 1 and 4 win their respective "best of 5" series, thus advancing to the next round

### Where am I stuck?:

- I could introduce manually "Team 1" in F6  cell and "Team 4" in F8 cell, but I want determine the winner automatically with a formula.
- I've made this formula but is incomplete and I'm stuck continuing it:

  > =IF(AND(D2>=0;D2<=3;D4>=0;D4<=3;NO(D2=D4));IF(D2>D4;B2;B4);"Error, must be between 0 and 3")
- Things working:

  - Introduce numbers between 0 and 3
  - The team with te greatest score is the winner, (if Team 1 is 3 and Team 2 is 0, Team 1 is the winner)
- Things NOT working:

  Control of incomplete matches:

  - If I introduce 1-0,2-0,2-1, it shows the winer is Team 1, but it should show an error message "incomplete result"
  - If I introduce 0-1,0-1,1-2, it shows the winer is Team 2, but it should show an error message ""incomplete result""
  - If I introduce 1-1,2-2,3-3, it shows "Error, must be between 0 and 3" but I want to show a differerent message for this error

Comment: what you are describing is overall sheet or workbook design. There are many steps involved, can you narrow down what you need to start?

Comment: Edited with an example an a better explanation

Comment: I just want to point out here that the only possible win condition is a value of "3", so get rid of all the tests for 0,1,2. If you find a 3, then you have a winner, use the team name.

Comment: @Yorik Just want to select the winner only when match is ended. if final score is 1-0 o 2-1... the match didn't ended yet  and sholud show the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to improve conditionals a bit, but you're on the good way. The logic of the formula will be quite straightforward:

- `=IF(C3+C4=0,"Not played"`
  At first check whether both scores are 0 (I suppose negative scores aren't entered)
- `,IF(MAX(C3:C4)<3,"Error, incomplete results"`
  ELSE, check whether both scores are less then 3 (actually it's enough to compare only the bigger one)
- `,IF(C3=C4,"Error, The final score cannot be a tie"`
  ELSE, check whether both scores are 3 (we've checked before whether both of them are less then 3, now we checks whether they're equal, if both are true, that means that both numbers are 3)
- `,IF(C3>C4,B3,B4)`
  ELSE, (if we didn't found any mistake) get the team name corresponding to the higher score
- `)))`
  and finally, don't forget to close all the brackets:)

The whole formula:
`=IF(C3+C4=0,"Not played",IF(MAX(C3:C4)<3,"Error, incomplete results",IF(C3=C4,"Error, The final score cannot be a tie",IF(C3>C4,B3,B4))))`

[image]